# Error: 'set_envvar' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

Tags: r

I'm trying to run Data Exploration in my R Studio, version 1.3.959 on my windows10.I wrote following test code

```
if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("boxuancui/DataExplorer", ref = "develop")
library(DataExplorer)
diabetes_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", header = FALSE)
names(diabetes_data) <- c("number_of_times_pregnant", "plasma_glucose_conc", "diastolic_bp", "triceps_skinfold_thickness", "two_hr_serum_insulin", "bmi", "diabetes_pedigree_function", "age", "label")
# create report
create_report(diabetes_data)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
Error: 'set_envvar' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and updating my packages solved the issue, especially the package `xfun` from which `set_envvar` is originated.